# Dozer, how to map using methods result

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

Have for exemple two classes :

```
public class A
{
    public int doSomething()
    {
        return 12;
    }
}

public class B
{
    private int something;

    public int getSomething()
    {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(int s)
    {
        something = s;
    }
}
```

Can I map the result of `doSomething()` in `A` to something in `B` ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible , because Dozer do field to field level mapping by using reflection , now it can be implicit (if fields name are same) and explicit (if fields name are different.) . So, if you want to use Dozer you should have corresponding source and destination field available in your source and destination clasess.

But in your `Class A` , I am not able to see anyfield , so how you will do the mapping.
More importantly setter and getter for any field should also be present otherwise you will get a run time exception until and unless you are using custom getter and setter method approach, same is missing in your `Class A`.

Please have a look at [dozer framework](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/gettingstarted.html).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but you can try the custom get/set methods route as mentioned [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html)